# rake db:seed fails b/c .specification lacks expected '-' indicator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run `rake db:seed`, I get the error:

`(<my rails root>/vendor/gems/tzinfo-0.3.30/.specification): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 1 column 1`

I am lost. Can anyone give me a clue? Here's the content of the .specification file: http://pastie.org/4898962

*Specs: rails 2.3.5, ruby 1.8.7*

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake gems:refresh_specs` first, then `rake db:seed`.

The `.specification` file was (apparently) defunct.